# tqdm makes map async

Tags: python, asynchronous, tqdm

I wanted to add a progress bar to my map functions. But after adding `tqdm` to them, they seem to be asynchronous. The coding:

```
 print("---> First…")
 res = map(func1, tqdm(res))

 print("---> Second…")
 res = map(func2, tqdm(res))
```

The output on terminal:

> ```
> ---> First…   
>   0%|                                        | 0/607 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
> ---> Second… 
> 100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 607/607 [00:01<00:00,
>  382.76it/s] 607it [00:01, 382.76it/s]
> ```

Is there any chance to get them synchronous?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by asynchronous and synchronous here? Are they executed concurrently somehow?

Comment: Yes, I mean concurrently. I have ``print``s in ``func1`` and ``func2`` and it seems that they are called in parallel or alternating. Also it's using only one progress bar (together?), the first one is standing still on 0 %.

Comment: `tqdm` messes with the cursor. It keeps moving it back and forth so it can update the progress bar. You shouldn't print anything from functions wrapped by it. I don't think things are actually running concurrently, it's probably just the output that gets messed up.

Comment: In the debugger, it is just going over these maps without additional waiting time (like they are spawned in own threads) - although these maps are CPU-intensive and should take a while (therefore the progress bar). I tested with another map (without tqdm) and the debugger halts and waits.

Comment: Do you see additional threads being created? That should be easy to check with a debugger and/or Process Explorer. It's hard to tell what the issue is without an example that can reproduce this.

Comment: After further analysis, I also don't think it's a thread thing. But it's hard to tell what's the problem. I tried to reproduce it with a toy example, but I'm not able to do it. Considering both, the only thing and difference I noticed is that the function ``__iter__`` of ``class tqdm`` (_tqdm.py) is called after the outer function of the maps reaches its end while with a toy example it is called immediately.